# NOT getting updated content with every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js. I'm facing a problem where I am not able to **load my new content on the page.** Next.js keeps showing the *old content* which I already *deleted* from the code. Why does prior content show?

Here is the last code which I delete but still it is showing on the source tab of chrome.

```js
export const UploadWrapper = () => {
    // const img__isClicked = ;
    const img__isClicked = useSelector(state => state);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('uploadWrapper', img__isClicked);
    }, [img__isClicked])

    return (
        <section>
            <UploadDropzone />
            {(img__isClicked) ? console.log('hurray I got you') : null }
        </section>
    )
}
```

Here is the updated code which is not showing on the page:

```js
export const UploadWrapper = () => {
    // const img__isClicked = ;
    const img__isClicked = useSelector(state => state.img__isClicked);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('uploadWrapper', img__isClicked);
    }, [img__isClicked])

    return (
      <>
        <section>
            <UploadDropzone />
        </section>
        <aside>
            {(img__isClicked === true) ? <TagsWrapper /> : null }
        </aside>
      </>
    )
}
```

If I wish to see fresh content then I have to restart the whole server again.

event the console is showing me

> Hurray I got you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because new render doesn't happen when you don't change the state inside the component. You could create imgClicked state like this:

```
export const UploadWrapper = () => {
  const [imgClicked, setImageClicked] = useState(false);
  const img__isClicked = useSelector(state => state.img__isClicked);

  useEffect(() => {
    setImageClicked(img__isClicked); // <--- This state change will trigger re-render of the component.
  }, [img__isClicked])

  return (
    <>
      {imgClicked ? <TagsWrapper /> : null}
    </>
  )
}
```